# CucumberException when trying to generate Cucumber reports

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, report

I am trying to generate different types of reports for cucumber test execution.

At first I was working with the basic report as follow

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/features"},
        tags = {"@Search"},
        plugin = {
                "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml",
                "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",}
)

public class TestRunner {
}
```

But now I am trying to generate other reports in order to share with the team and decide which would be more usefull.

```
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "target/cucumber.json",
        retryCount = 3,
        detailedReport = true,
        detailedAggregatedReport =true,
        overviewReport = true,
        coverageReport = true,
        jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-usage.json",
        toPDF = true,
        includeCoverageTags = {"@chrome"},
        outputFolder = "target"
)

@CucumberOptions(
        strict = true,
        features = {"src/test/features"},
        tags = {"@Search"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty:STDOUT",
                "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml",
                "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
        monochrome = true,
        glue = ("com.cucumber.test")
)

public class TestRunner {
}
```

But when I execute the test runner a cucumber exception is returned.

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
```

According what I have been checking on blogs could be related some dependencies.
However I am following different guides but I can not fix it.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mkolisnyk/cucumber-runner -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
                <groupId>fop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
```

Basically what I want to obtain is a report included in a pdf file in order team can review the results from there.

Also any other idea about how can the team visualize the html report that is pushed to github would be welcome (we will avoid Jenkins).